# Zengallery imagepath pattern

Tags: orchardcms

I was hoping Bertand could answer this since he wrote the module zen gallery :)

I want to be able to choose my `product.Sku` as imagepath (pattern) but I don't know how to write the pattern.

I have a `productpart` attached to my `productcontenttype` but if I enter `/productimages/{Content.ProductPart.Sku}` as my pattern the module is not able to pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the setting that I use on nwazet.com: `product/{Content.Sku}`

This is using Nwazet Commerce, which provides the sku token.

Comment: Ok thanks but when I try that I will get an exception in Nwazet.ZenGallery.Drivers.ZenGalleryPartDriver at ZenGalleryService.cs:row 97.



The method is CreateFolder(String relativePath, String folderName) and its passing in empty string into foldername. Do you have custom tokenprovider for your productpart?

Comment: Ok I implemented a tokenprovider for my module and Content.Sku is populated now. But the same exception is thrown when I create a new product and leaves the gallery image path - field empty. Strange thing is that when I first create the product and edit it afterwards and leaves the field blank its working. Bug?

Comment: Bug, certainly, but in whose code, that is the question. Works perfectly fine with Nwazet.Commerce, so...

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks for your time though. I will debug the code and see if something comes up

Comment: Hello, Just wanted to say that this seems ok now. Cleared the Nwazet_ZenGallery_ZenGalleryPartRecord dbtable from a lot of NULL-values and now I am able to have the path like Products/Images/{Content.Sku} and the module will generate correct path for me. Great and thanks for a nice module!